# android timer view(just like progress bar) updating with colors in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-activity, progress

i my app, when i enter a activity i am showing a timer view (looks like a progress bar) which runs based on a timer value from server. At start(eg 40sec) timer will be of green and in middle(eg 25 sec) changes to yellow and finally to red(eg 10 sec), following is my code which i am using

```
public class TimerView extends View 
{
    private LinearInterpolator mInterpolator;
    private Transformation mTransformation;
    private AlphaAnimation mAnimation;

    int orange = Color.rgb(255, 153, 0);
    private int green = Color.rgb(107, 155, 21);
    private int red = Color.rgb(194, 21, 30);
    private int yellow = Color.rgb(225, 170, 0);

    private RectF rect;
    private Integer mTimerVal = 0;
    private Paint tmrPaint;
    private Paint txtPaint;
    private float mDensity = 1.0f;

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        txtPaint = new Paint();
        tmrPaint = new Paint();
        tmrPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        txtPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtPaint.setTextSize(15.0f * mDensity);
        txtPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            txtPaint.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(getContext(), "OpenSans-CondBold.ttf"));
        }
        rect = new RectF(0, 8 * mDensity, 0, 22 * mDensity);
        mInterpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        // Timer Animation
        mTransformation = new Transformation();
        mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(AlphaAnimation.RESTART);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        mAnimation.setDuration(0);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
        mAnimation.setStartTime(Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
        mAnimation.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        // System.out.println("onLayout: " + left + " top: " + top + " r: " +
        // right + " b: " + bottom);
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // System.out.println("onLayout onMeasure: " + widthMeasureSpec + " x "
        // + heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        long time = getDrawingTime();
        mAnimation.getTransformation(time, mTransformation);
        float scale = mTransformation.getAlpha();

        int rem = (int) Math.floor(mTimerVal * scale);
        if (rem > 0) 
        {
            if (rem < 5) 
            {
                tmrPaint.setColor(red);
            }
            else if (rem <= 10) 
            {
                tmrPaint.setColor(yellow);
            }
            else 
            {
                tmrPaint.setColor(green);
            }

            rect.right = this.getWidth() - mDensity * 8;
            rect.left = (1 - scale) * (this.getWidth());

            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 4 * mDensity, 4 * mDensity, tmrPaint);
            canvas.drawText(String.format("%d", rem), 13 * mDensity, 20 * mDensity, txtPaint);
        }
        if (scale > 0.0f) {
            postInvalidateDelayed(40);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setTimer(TimerTag timer) {
        if (timer.getTimerValue() > 0) {
            mAnimation.reset();
            mTimerVal = timer.getTimerValue();
            mAnimation.setDuration(timer.getTimerValue() * 1000);
            mAnimation.start();
            postInvalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Now my problem is when i enter the activity, if the server response is below 25 and above 10 my timer is showing yellow color, but it gets started from end, i want it to be started from middle or some other position in the view, i am not able to change the start point in canvas, any suggestions.....

Answer (score 0):

Since the rectangle co-ordinates (especially left-top) is being calculated based on the current alpha value, the starting alpha value of the `AlphaAnimation` should be based on the time already elapsed.

e.g. If the timer was set for 30 seconds and user enters the activity at 10th second, then animation need to be played for 20 seconds. So the start alpha value should be 20/30 i.e. 0.67f. `AlphaAnimation`  should be instantiated as below:

```
mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.67f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: this idea cannot be implemented. In onDraw based on integer rem value i am changing the color of progress bar, there we cant insert this line....

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you draw rect, which always at the right:

```
rect.right = this.getWidth() - mDensity * 8;
```

And your left edge of rect is depends on scale:

```
 rect.left = (1 - scale) * (this.getWidth());
```

I think you simply need to change it to:

```
rect.right = this.getWidth() - mDensity * 8 - (1-scale) * this.getWidth();
rect.left = 0;
```

Comment: those two lines are to reduce from left to right, if i change as you said it will reduce from right to left....